# Get the result of a Task without a callback

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation, android-task

I am currently trying to migrate all my location calls to use the new [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) model flow but one question I have is that is there a way to get the result of a task without having to wait for a callback?

The reason I ask is because I need to get the last location inside an async task before I save something to my database but since I am already in another thread I shouldn't have to worry about something taking time plus isnt having a callback inside an async task bad?

The documentation says `task.getResult()` only gives you a result once it has completed

So my question is, is there anyway to execute this synchronously?

using this as reference

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: "isnt having a callback inside an async task bad" That depends on what thread calls the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already in a background thread, you can indeed execute the task synchronously. For this, the [new API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#await(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3CTResult%3E)) is now:

```
Result result = Tasks.await(task);
```